# How are python's unpacking operators * and ** used?

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing, iterable-unpacking, argument-unpacking

The unpacking/splat operators `*` and `**` differ widely in their applicability across python versions (2.7, 3.x < 3.5 and 3.x >= 3.5).

For example:

```
                                   |   2.7    |   3.1-3.4  |   3.5   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
function(*args)                         ✓            ✓          ✓    

x, *y, z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]              x            ✓          ✓    

{**x, **y}                              x            x          ✓
```

Are there any more discrepancies between the various versions that I've missed?  I'm looking through PEP and Readmes but the docs aren't detailed with this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Around 1992 (not sure about Python version). This is from the Grammar file of [Python 1.0.1](http://legacy.python.org/download/releases/src/).

```
# 06-Apr-92:
#   Use only '*' for varargs list

# 31-Mar-92:
#   Tighten syntax for try statements

# 27-Feb-92:
#   Allow NEWLINE* after eval input

# 16-Jan-92:
#   Added '*' as alternative for '+' in varargs syntax
#   (Not sure which alternative is better yet.)

# 11-Jan-92:
#   Variable length argument list syntax added: def f(a, b, +rest): ...
```

[Python 1.4+](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/tut/node105.html#SECTION001310000000000000000):

> **Keyword Arguments**: Functions and methods written in Python can now be
>   called using keyword arguments of the form `keyword = value`.

[Python 1.6+](https://www.python.org/download/releases/1.6/)

> There's now special syntax that you can use instead of the [`apply()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply)
>   function. `f(*args, **kwds)` is equivalent to `apply(f, args, kwds)`. You
>   can also use variations `f(a1, a2, *args, **kwds)` and you can leave one
>   or the other out: `f(*args)`, `f(**kwds)`.

[Python <= 2.7](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html):

Tuple parameter unpacking was removed in Python 3.0.

> [PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113): **Tuple parameter
>   unpacking removed.** You can no longer write `def foo(a, (b, c)): ...`.
>   Use `def foo(a, b_c): b, c = b_c` instead.

[Python 3.0+](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)

> [PEP 3132](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132): **Extended Iterable
>   Unpacking**. You can now write things like `a, b, *rest =
>   some_sequence`. And even `*rest, a = stuff`. The rest object is always
>   a (possibly empty) list; the right-hand side may be any iterable.
>
> [PEP 3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102): **Keyword-only arguments.** Named parameters occurring after
>   `*args` in the parameter list must be specified using keyword syntax in the call. You can also use a bare `*` in the parameter list to indicate
>   that you don’t accept a variable-length argument list, but you do have
>   keyword-only arguments

[Python 3.5+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations)

> [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), additional
>   unpacking generalizations.

---

As far as I know there's no single page that lists all the syntax changes. Per version syntax changes are listed in the [What's new in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/index.html) section or you could check the Grammar specification of each release to see the differences.

Comment: Nice research; when was the 'varargs' syntax ( *name ) introduced? This pre-dates Python 3 (or was possibly backported)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Did you mean the one used in assignment?

Comment: I meant like `max(*(1,2,3))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands This was added in Python 1.6. Updated in answer.

Comment: But, simply doing: `max((1, 2, 3, 4))` works fine. So, what's the advantage of explicit *unpacking*?

Comment: @kmario23 Yes, `max()` and `min()` work with both iterable and individual arguments, but that was just an example from Chris.