# What does the asterisk do in *a, b, c = line.split()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asterisk, iterable-unpacking, argument-unpacking

Assume `line` is: `"Chicago Sun 01:52"`.

What does `*a, b, c = line.split()` do? In particular, what is the significance of the asterisk?

Edit: Upon testing it, it seems like `"Chicago"`, `"Sun"` and `"01:52"` are all stored in `a`, `b` and `c`. The asterisk seems to lead to `"Chicago"` being stored in a as the first element of a list. So, we have `a = ["Chicago"]`, `b = "Sun"` and `c = "01:52"`. Could anyone point to material on the functionality of the asterisk operator in this situation?

Comment: What do you see in the variables when you try this?

Comment: See documentation [PEP 3132 -- Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Comment: The asterisk means something of arbitrary length (called star unpacking). So everything up until the last three elements in your `line.split()` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Splitting that text by whitespace will give you:

```
In [743]: line.split()
Out[743]: ['Chicago', 'Sun', '01:52']
```

Now, this is a 3 element `list`. The assignment will take the last two elements of the output and assign them to `b` and `c` respectively. The `*`, or the *splat* operator will then pass the remainder of that list to `a`, and so `a` is a list of elements. In this case, `a` is a single-element list.

```
In [744]: *a, b, c = line.split()

In [745]: a
Out[745]: ['Chicago']

In [746]: b
Out[746]: 'Sun'

In [747]: c
Out[747]: '01:52'
```

Look at [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) and [Where are python's splat operators * and ** valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346116/where-are-pythons-splat-operators-and-valid) for more information on the splat operators, how they work and where they're applicable.