# Python string interpolation with splat operator?

Tags: python, string-interpolation, splat

I have a large (~10 elements) list of integers that I wish to interpolate into a string. This seems like an ideal use case for the splat operator, so I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
"""[latex]$\begin{bmatrix}
%d & %d \\ %d & %d\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
%d & %d \\ %d & %d
\end{bmatrix} $[/latex]""" % (*lst)
                              ^^^^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is a clean, syntactically valid way to achieve this?

Comment: Ignacio has given the correct answer, but it is important to note that this also just an invalid usage of the * splat operator in Python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346116/where-are-pythons-splat-operators-and-valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.__mod__` takes a tuple.

```
'''...''' % tuple(lst)
```