# Combine lists into a meshgrid parameter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm using this function that works well to give me a numpy array of all possible combinations of arrays

```
 arrs = np.array(np.meshgrid([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])).T.reshape(-1,3)
```

But what I would like to do is take the 3 lists and create the meshgrid parameter like this:

```
lst1=[1,2,3]
lst2=[4,5,6]
lst3=[7,8,9]

arrs = np.array(np.meshgrid(lst)).T.reshape(-1,3)
```

But how can I create lst from the 3 lists?  If I do this

```
lst=[lst1,lst2,lst3]
```

all I get is an error.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to unpack the `lst`:

```
# notice the *
arrs = np.array(np.meshgrid(*lst)).T.reshape(-1,3)
```

Comment: For future reference, this method is called "iterable unpacking". See https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45346333/7473705