# How to input a vector of arguments in a function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function, which takes a variable number of inputs. For example, the functions may look like `fn(a0,a1,...)`. Now, I have a vector `A=[a0,a1,...]`, and I want to call `fn`, but I'm not sure how to dynamically set the number of inputs (if handling outside of the function). I do not want to handle this inside the function.

How can I do this?

Comment: can u share some code

Comment: You use argument spreading: `fn(*A)`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346116/how-are-pythons-unpacking-operators-and-used) answer your question? In particular, I _think_ you're looking for `fn(*A)` unless I'm missing something.

Comment: And the function should be defined `def fn(*a):`

Comment: The `*` operator was what I was looking for. Thanks! I thought the `*` operator only worked on the inside of the function not the outside as well